# Startup commands in /etc/rc.local won't work

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi

I have a Python program and an nginx/uwsgi/django web setup. I want the program to start with the system, as well as the web server.

Here's my `/etc/rc.local`:

```
crawler_dir=/home/mohammed/git/crawler
log_dir=$crawler_dir/logs
client_rundir=$crawler_dir/rundirs/client
server_rundir=$crawler_dir/rundirs/server
site_dir=$crawler_dir/whoissite
env_dir=/home/mohammed/pyenvs/whoisenv

$env_dir/bin/python $env_dir/bin/twistd --logfile=$log_dir/twistd_server.log --pidfile=$server_rundir/twistd.pid$
$env_dir/bin/python $env_dir/bin/twistd --logfile=$log_dir/twistd_client.log --pidfile=$client_rundir/twistd.pid client -n Pikatchu

$env_dir/bin/uwsgi $site_dir/uwsgi.ini
```

the `uwsgi.ini`:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /home/mohammed/git/crawler
socket = whoissite.sock 
module = whoissite.wsgi
daemonize = ../logs/uwsgi.log 
chmod-socket=666
```

So I have a Python virtualenv and I make sure I run executables from it, so they don't run with the default Python which is not properly setup.

The trick is, I can run these commands by hand just fine from the terminal, just not from the startup.

The log files from **twistd** and **uwsgi** just aren't created, so I don't know what went wrong. How can I get these to run.

Thanks

Comment: Add `set -x; exec >/var/log/rc.local.log 2>&1` at the top of `/etc/rc.local` just below the `#!/bin/sh` line. After the next reboot, look at the file `/var/log/rc.local.log` to see what shell commands were excuted and what output they produced. Did you try running these commands as root? Do you want to run them as root? Is your home directory encrypted?

Comment: @Gilles thanks a lot. The log file indicated what seems like the same problem for the app and webserver; both of them don't read the contents of `/etc/environment` to see the `PYTHONPATH` setting there, thus throwing import errors. That was fixed by adding `pythonpath = /path/to/mywebapp` in `uwsgi.ini`, but I don't know how can I do the same for `twistd`.

Comment: I modified `twistd` executable to include the plugin directory and it seems to work: `sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/plugindir")`. It's a bit hackish, is there any formal approach?